# Can I perform calculations on dates easily with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a 'streak' tracker. A user sets a date, and then they have a button to update, or restart, their streak to 0. Is there an easy way in Ruby on Rails to determine the streak by subtracting the date the streak was set from the current date?

Comment: The Date class should provide you with what you need -- example `Date.yesterday - Date.today` will return a Fixnum of 1 day. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html to view the methods that are exposed for the Date class